# Limit one timer active at a time

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

We have started a timer with the following code. Is it possible to make window.setInterval method fail, if another timer is active on the method passed to the `window.setInterval` method?

```
GInterValId = window.setInterval("AutoRefresh()",parseInt(GRefreshInterval));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you do is set up a system for this. Create an object that handle all your Timers:

```
var Timer = function () {
   var currentTimer;

   this.setTimer = function (func,time) {
      if (currentTimer) {
           alert("one timer already set");
      }else {
          currentTimer = setInterval(func,time);
      }
   }

   this.stopTimer = function () {
      clearInterval(currentTimer);
      currentTimer = null;
   }
}
```

Now you can use this code:

```
function doSomething() {...}      // function example
function doSomethingElse() {...}  // function example

var MyTimer = new Timer();

MyTimer.setTimer(doSomething,1000); // this will run

MyTimer.setTimer(doSomethingElse,1000); // this will not run
```

The second one will not run because the other one is active.
to make it work you have clear the first one.

```
MyTimer.stopTimer(); // will clear the current timer then you can run another one
MyTimer.setTimer(doSomethingElse,1000); // will run perfectly
```

Comment: When you clear the interval, you also want to reset the value of *currentTime* else you won't be able to start another one, even if the current one has been stopped.

Comment: @RobG: You are right, i have set currentTimer to null, this way it will not pass the first condition and will set the new timer

Answer (score 1):

If you keep track of the result result from window.setInterval(), you can stop the previous interval timer at any point.

```
var GInterValId = setInterval(AutoRefresh, parseInt(GRefreshInterval));
```

Then, when you want to reset it:

```
if (GInterValId) {
   clearInterval(GInterValId);
}
GInterValId = setInterval(AutoRefresh, parseInt(GRefreshInterval));
```

Also note that I'm not passing a string to setInterval, but an actual JS function reference.

Or, if you just want to prevent another interval getting set:

```
var GInterValId = null;  // initialize

// then, when you want to set it, check to see if it's already been set
if (GInterValId) {
    GInterValId = setInterval(AutoRefresh, parseInt(GRefreshInterval));
}
```

Comment: Won't the statement if (GInterValId) {clearTimeout(GInterValId);} create a race condition if multiple threads checks the condition simultaneously

Comment: There is no race condition.  Javascript does not have multiple threads.  It is single threaded so one thread of execution must run to completion before the next can run.

Comment: We have seen multiple alert boxes appear on the same page. I assume that multiple threads will be running simultaneously

Comment: Alerts are a weird beast and an exception, but still no race condition.  The thread that put up the alert is "not" running at that time - it's blocked by the alert.  One thread of JS execution won't be pre-emptively interrupted by another thread like it can be in C/C++.